# How to restrict external access to a specific sub-URL IIS7

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7

I've currently got a reasonably large site up that i've been asked to make changes to. 
Currently To login to this site you need to go to:
www.example.com/folder/loginpage.html
This site is only accessible internally at this time and it is unlikely to ever be accessible externally.
We would like to, however, be able to direct external users to a sub-directory on the site (a 'survey' form) which is located in
www.example.com/folder/subfolder/survey.html 
This survey writes its results back to the main application and i believe they are integrated tightly.

We initially tried the idea of using an additional IIS7 box as a reverse proxy however it is quite confusing to me, i'm not very familiar with IIS/ARR and the other features required (i'm mostly familiar with networking). I did try and follow a number of tutorials but didn't get very far. I'd like to avoid it if possible.

How can I, using IIS7 (this site is in ASP.NET) restrict external users from accessing anything other than the survey pages (there are a few included files necessary as well)?
Is it possible to make www.example.com/folder/subfolder/survey.html a 'website' in-itself so that i can publish a URL like survey.example.com externally?

I've come across other examples where access is restricted from specific pages but the root of the site is still accessible 
ie
www.eg.com/ is allowed but www.eg.com/admin.aspx is denied. I'd like to the the reverse in effect, and if possible, hide the 'true' url.

Hope someone can help! If using a reverse proxy is possible i'm happy to do it but i'd need detailed instructions.

Thanks for reading,
Much appreciated!

Edit: Sorry all, I'm new to stackoverflow, indeed I've just realised that there are several other sub-communities. Is it more appropriate to ask this in a different community? If so, which one?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between an "internal" and "external" user?  Is it IP-based?

Comment: @tspauld yes, external is internet facing while internal is 172.16.x.x network only